# What did 'prō' mean in 'prōrogō' ? What is its Semantic Field?

Tags: etymology

> [ [Etymonline :](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=prorogation) ]   [...]   from Latin *prorogare*, literally "to ask publicly,"
> from *pro* "before" (see [pro-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pro-&allowed_in_frame=0)) + *rogare* "to ask" (see [rogation](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=rogation&allowed_in_frame=0)). Perhaps the original sense in Latin was "to ask for public assent to extending someone's term in office."

[*Oxford Latin Dictionary* (2012 2 ed)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0199580316). p 1648-1649.

> [image]

1. What precisely does the prefix *prō* mean here?
2. How did the prefix *prō* combine with the root *rogō* to produce meaning 4 above?

> [ [Wiktionary :](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prorogo#Latin) ] From [prō](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pro#Latin) + [rogō](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rogo#Latin) ‎(“ask; request”).
> 4. I defer, put off, postpone.

3. Doesn't Wiktionary's meaning 1 (Legislative meaning "discontinue temporarily")  mean the same as Wiktionary's meaning 4?

Comment: I took the liberty of formatting your question so that it is a little clearer. Any particular reason why in this question and many others you indent and number your lists in a different way?

Comment: I'm guessing *pro* means "forward in time; into the future". So you're asking for something to happen in the future. But the details remain misty.

Comment: @brianpck Sorry for the confusion, but I have reverted most of the edits because: #1 was added by me and is not part of the original quote; I use only one digit once to prevent ambiguity. However, what else can I change to improve my post?

Answer (score 3):

**Short version:**

I. "forth, publicly"

II. It always meant "prolong, extend; delay" It just gets used often to say the same thing, in this case "ask publicly [for more time]"

III. Yes.

**Adventurous version:**

Some things to clarify before I address the questions:

1. In Latin, *pro* does not really mean 8 separate things. It's one or two basic ideas that we can translate 8+ ways.
2. You've looked up *pro* the **preposition**, rather than *pro* the **prefix**.
3. *pro* the prefix, according to Keller & Russell (*Learn to Read Latin*) has these common translations: "forward, forth; in front of"

And now for each question:

**I**.
Let's use that first translation of Keller and Russell, "forward, forth." In *prorogare* we are literally saying "ask forth." A more fun word, *promulgare*, literally translates "milk forth." But we know it really means to promulgate, report publicly, or expose publicly.

As we can see, *pro* in both verbs means "**forth**" in the sense of "**publicly**."

**II**. It's not that *pro* "combines" with *rogo* differently from the "literal" *pro+rogo*. Instead, the word *prorogo* is used more in certain contexts. But what contexts? Let's look at its common direct objects. Cicero and Livy used *prorogo* to ask for more *imperium* (the privilege of commanding an army, which has a time limit).

From the Lewis & Short (via Perseus' Latin Word Study Tool):

> ne quinquennii imperium Caesari prorogaretur, - lest for 5
> years the imperium of Caesar **be prolonged**, Cic. Phil. 2, 10, 24.

[Link to the full lexicon entry. Click on "Lewis & Short" or "Elem Lewis" for the info](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=prorogo&la=la#Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=prorogo-contents)

I think this example shows how "ask publicly for more imperium" clearly means "[ask to] prolong imperium."

If this hasn't yet convinced you, some other nouns used with *prorogo* include *spatium*, or "span/extent (of time)" and *mora*, delay. Or to use the sense of "defer": *dies ad solvendum*, day of being freed, and my personal favorite, *diem mortis*, day of death. And there we have that legal meaning, "**discontinue temporarily"** from the sense of "delay."

**III**. Legislative meaning means it's found in legal documents. Probably, it was a common courtroom/legal phrase, like *pro bono*. There is no reason for courts to change its meaning.